# Thermistor in Tikz circuit library

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

Is there a symbol like a thermistor in the Tikz circuit library? I read the documentation and couldn't find anything like it. There is a symbol for a varistor but what I'm looking for would be something like this:

[image: thermistor]

rather than this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that by using

```
\usepackage{circuitikz}
```

you don't need use

```
\begin{circuitikz}
...
\end{circuitikz}
```

inside an existing `tikzpicture`, you can just simply access `circuitikz` elements like

```
\draw (0,0) to[thR] (2,0);
```

using the same coordinates as the rest of the `tikzpicture`
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need the version `0.3.0` of the `circuitikz` package to draw thermistors. Once you have installed it, use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[thR] (2,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

as you can see in the [manual](http://ctan.mackichan.com/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf) at page 10.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the `circuitikz`library but the `Tikz`circuit library? Or if not then is it possible to do this inside a `tikzpicture`?

Comment: Circuitikz runs under Tikz.  All of the Tikz library, in fact all Tikz plotting features, are available from Circuitikz.  (If you want, you can connect components using decorations.)

Comment: Could you tell me how I could connect these two using the same coordinates, or where I could find an example? I tried opening a `circuitikz`inside a `tikzpicture` but that was obviously not the right approach.

Comment: @DavidWright I don't know how to connect the two, I use directly `circuitikz` for design the whole circuit (see some example at the end of the manual)